# Posted json not reflected in object parameter

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc, typescript

In my webapplication I'm posting a message object in json-format to save it to the database. With the devtools in Firefox I can see valid json being posted but when debugging the server code (MVC c#) the parameter object of type Message has an empty title and body property.

The object definition in typescript:

```
export interface IMessage {
    title: string;
    body: string;
    isHidden: boolean;
}
```

The code to post the object to the server:

```
public postNewMessage(message: IMessage)
{
    return this.http.postJson("/messages/newmessage", message);
}
```

The json i see posted to the webserver:

```
{"title":"title","body":"body message","isHidden":true}
```

The server code:

```
[HttpPost("newmessage")]
public async Task<JsonResult> Post(MessageSummary message)
{
}
```

C# class definition of Message

```
public class MessageSummary
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string title { get; set; }
    public string body { get; set; }
    public author author { get; set; }
}
```

So when i set a breakpoint on the server sideaction the message object is not null but the title and body property are empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured this out, the solution was actually rather simple, by just adding the [FromBody] I got the posted object data:

```
[HttpPost("newmessage")]
public async Task<JsonResult> Post([FromBody] MessageSummary message)
{
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've never used typescript before but is this `,` next to body not meant to be a `:`?

```
export interface IMessage {
    title: string;
    body, string;
    isHidden: boolean;
}
```

Comment: That was actually just a typo in my post and not in the actual code, edited my post. Thanks for pointing this out.